# SQL Server 2008 R2 - converting columns to rows and have all values in one column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, dynamic-sql, transpose, unpivot

I am having a hard time trying to wrap my head around the pivot/unpivot concepts and hoping someone can help or give me some guidance on how to approach my problem.

Here is a simplified sample table I have

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
| SAUID | COM1 | COM2 | COM3 | COM4 | COM5 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1     | 24   | 22   | 100  | 0    | 45   |
| 2     | 34   | 55   | 789  | 23   | 0    |
| 3     | 33   | 99   | 5552 | 35   | 4675 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

The end result I am looking for a table result similar below

```
+-------+-----------+-------+
| SAUID | OCCUPANCY | VALUE |
+-------+-----------+-------+
| 1     | COM1      | 24    |
| 1     | COM2      | 22    |
| 1     | COM3      | 100   |
| 1     | COM4      | 0     |
| 1     | COM5      | 45    |
| 2     | COM1      | 34    |
| 2     | COM2      | 55    |
| 2     | COM3      | 789   |
| 2     | COM4      | 23    |
| 2     | COM5      | 0     |
| 3     | COM1      | 33    |
| 3     | COM2      | 99    |
| 3     | COM3      | 5552  |
| 3     | COM4      | 35    |
| 3     | COM5      | 4675  |
+-------+-----------+-------+
```

Im looking around but most of the examples seem to use pivot but having a hard time trying to wrap that around my case as I need the values all in one column.

I hoping to experiment with some hardcoding to get fimilar with my example but my actual table columns are ~100 with varying #s of SAUID per table and looks like it will require dynamic sql?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT u.SAUID, u.OCCUPANCY, u.VALUE
FROM yourTable t
UNPIVOT
(
    VALUE for OCCUPANCY in (COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5)
) u;
ORDER BY
    u.SAUID, u.OCCUPANCY;
```

[image]

### Demo